# running loop for 5 minutes

Tags: java

I have a requirment to run a while loop the 5 min.
I looked for the timer api but I could not found to do this.
Can any one provide a code snipet for this.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550536/java-loop-for-a-certain-duration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way will be to just check how much time has elapsed on each iteration. Example:

```
final long NANOSEC_PER_SEC = 1000l*1000*1000;

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
while ((System.nanoTime()-startTime)< 5*60*NANOSEC_PER_SEC){
  // do stuff
}
```

This will run the loop, until more than 5 minutes have elapsed.

Notes:

1. The current loop iteration will always complete, so in practice it will always run for a bit more than 5 minutes.
2. For this application `System.nanoTime()` is more suitable than `System.currentTimeMillis()` because the latter will change if the computer's system clock is adjusted, thus throwing off the calculation. *Thanks to Shloim for pointing this out.*

Comment: If the user adjusts his clock while your loop is running, then your loop will not run for 1 minute. It might run for months or years. That's because `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the amount of msecs since 1970/01/01-00:00:00. You need a time counter that is monotone, like `System.nanoTicks()`

Comment: Here is a clean solution without using system clock. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71611647/3190214

Answer (score 5):

This loop will run for 5 minutes. It will not be effected by changes made to the computer's date/time (either by user or by NTP).

```
long endTime = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
while ( System.nanoTime() < endTime ){
  // do whatever
}
```

Other methods like `System.currentTimeMillis()` should be avoided, because they rely on the computer date/time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are talking about the timer API I guess what you are after is a delay instead of a "loop running for 5min". If this is the case you could use something like [Thread.sleep(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) which would allow to let the CPU do more usefull stuff that busy-waiting. Or at least save some energy and the planet.

Comment: Yes, for a simple delay this is the right answer. The question is a bit unclear...