# JAVA: How to stop the execution of a function after a specific time?

Tags: java, executorservice, execution-time, callable, iterative-deepening

I want to implement iterative deepening (incremental tree building). This is the part of my code I will ask about:

```
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Set<Callable<Integer>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<Integer>>();

        callables.add(new Callable<Integer>() {
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                iterativeDeepening(depthLimit, board);
                return -1;
            }
        });
        callables.add(new Callable<Integer>() {
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                return 1;
            }
        });
        try{
            executorService.invokeAny(callables, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }catch(TimeoutException | InterruptedException ex){
            executorService.shutdown();
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
```

From what I read about invokeAny() with time limit it should end executing its Callable objects as soon as the deadline is reached. It works when I put long sleep instead of my function iterativeDeepening(depthLimit, board). How to make it work with my function? 
Below I paste the code to this function:

```
    public void iterativeDeepening(byte depthLimit, byte[] board){

    for(byte depth=1;depth<depthLimit;depth++){
        GameTree gameTree= new GameTree();
        byte[] tempBoard = new byte[14];
        for(byte i=0;i<14;i++){
            tempBoard[i] = board[i];
        }
        Node <byte[]> root= new Node<byte[]>(tempBoard, player);
        try {
            gameTree.buildGameTree(depth, root);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) {
            gameTree.eraseGameTree(depth,root);
            System.gc();
        }

        MiniMax minimax = new MiniMax(player);
        move= minimax.selectMove(depth, root);

    }
}
```

If you know a better way to make it or know how to successfully stop execution of my function please let me know. I tried also a Runnable Interface mentioned in this topic:
[How to stop execution after a certain time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252187/how-to-stop-execution-after-a-certain-time-in-java)
but it just worked the same.

Comment: If you want it to be self-contained, you can just store a variable of System.currentTimeMillis() before you enter the loop. Then check `if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= maxRunTime)` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: That's not a solution because inside a loop there is a function gameTree.buildGameTree(depth, root); which itself sometimes takes longer than the deadline which is crucial.

Comment: You can pass the start time in as a parameter. @AndreyChaschev is probably correct that your best bet is to just check for the interrupt. Interrupting a thread does not necessarily end it prematurely without checking for the interrupt yourself.

Comment: I already tried with the below solution which at first I thought will be legit but it didn't work for me- maybe it's my mistake (I'll paste the code later because deadline is coming). Passing time as a parameter is very simple and great idea. I'll try it now. Thanks!

Comment: If checking for the interrupt isn't working the other thing you can try is to sleep for some trivial time like 1ms and catch the InterruptedException. I don't know why, but I've had good luck with that in the case of a run away thread that did not see the flag.

Comment: You could try using thread dump to check where it hangs. This is the right place to insert a check for interruption.

Comment: I've read the thread from start and updated the answer - there is no legal way to stop your logic from outside in Java.

Answer (score 1):

After the timeout is reached, the `ExecutorService` will try to interrupt all the currently running tasks by calling `Thread.interrupt()` on them. This will put each of the threads to an interrupted state. `sleep()` quits when this state is set.

So adding this check:

```
if(Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
    return;
}
```

inside your function should do the job.

A tip for you thread termination:

```
try{
    executorService.invokeAny(callables, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch(TimeoutException | InterruptedException ex){
    //... ignore
} finally {
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(); <-- add this line if you want to wait for the computation to end
}
```

**UPDATE**

> That's not a solution because inside a loop there is a function gameTree.buildGameTree(depth, root); which itself sometimes takes longer than the deadline which is crucial.

As far as I know, there is no way to interrupt such function from outside. This function should check it's state from time to time. If it's a loop, consider checking the state on some or all of the iterations.

Comment: No... Unfortunately it's not a loop but a recursive function which acts very weird. At the beginning (of buildGameTree(...)) I added startTime as an argument and I'm checking at the beginning if the time is over. If so- I'm returning an exception which is caught and the result is returned.
Weird is that the time limit is very often exceeded even 2-3 times. I tried using both nanoTime() and currentTimeMillis() with the same result.

Comment: You might need to catch the exception explicitly on the top level of the thread.

Comment: Why not directly? Since I started to pass time as an argument I flattened those two functions. Catching looks like this:
try {gameTree.buildGameTree(depth, root, startTime, timeLimit);   
} catch (OutOfMemoryError | Exception e) {return move;}

Comment: Because `invokeAny` won't propagate exceptions from your thread if there is at least one successfully finished task. In this case you won't notice anything wrong is happening.