# Exit method after duration

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out a way to exit a method call if it takes more then say 2 seconds
to execute everything in its method's body. For example, I have a huge list of strings and 
want to iterate through the list but only iterate as much of the strings as I can in 2 seconds.
Say I have 9,000 objects in the list but can only iterate through 6,500 in 2 seconds, the method
should stop after 2 second. Is this even possible to accomplish? I searched and found how to stop a thread and timers (how to start a method after a certain duration) but nothing on how to exit a method after a duration.

```
public ArrayList<String> removeWords(){

   //Want some sort of timer here that stops method body after 2 seconds

   for(String current: words){

            words.remove(current);
   }
}

public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> wordList = removeWords();
        System.out.println("Number of words in list "+ wordList.size());
}
```

Comment: google is a great tool. This was the first article returned from the search "stop program execution after 1 second java" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252187/how-to-stop-execution-after-a-certain-time-in-java

Comment: There's no way to know how long some code will take to execute before it runs (we can guess its time complexity, but not a precise time). If you only want to execute a bulk of code for n seconds, a `Timer` of some description is what you need. Knowing how long code will take to run would solve the Halting Problem.

Comment: the anwser to that link doesn't help, i've seen the article though

Comment: If i implemented that while loop then i would iterate through the entire list and only would stop once the for each loop completes and check the while condition the second time around

Comment: @Calvin is there some way for you to iterate over a single item per loop?

Answer (score 3):

Even interrupting a thread using [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) requires you to periodically check to see if an interrupt has been requested (using [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) or `Thread.isInterrupted()`), and then decide what to do about it.

So a good general pattern would be to :

1. Accept a timeout (the usual pattern is `long timeout, TimeUnit unit`) in your processing method's parameters
2. Periodically (every *n* iterations of your loop, or even every iteration if it doesn't hurt your performance) check for the timeout and for interruption (using [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) and [`TimeUnit.toMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#method_summary) to do the comparisons).
3. return if either occurs

What you return if you timeout is up to you, but for interruption you could just throw a [`new InterruptedException()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

Of course, if you aren't going to launch your method in a separate thread then you don't need to worry about interruption checking - just the timeouts.

Answer (score 3):

*Premise: when iterating over a collection, to remove elements you must use the same iterator or you get an exception*:

```
Iterator<String> it = words.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  String word = it.next();
  if (shouldRemove(word))
    it.remove();
}
```

---

If the program you want to stop is a loop **and the single iteration does not contain anything that can block** you can simply calculate the end instant and check after an X number of iterations:

```
for (String word : words) {
  if (System.currentTimeMillis() > endInstant) {
    timedOut = true; // better store this
    break;
  // ...
}
```

Otherwise the usual (and more robust) approach is wrapping your program in a `Callable<E>` and using a separate thread:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Result> promise = executor.submit(callable);
Result result = promise.get(10, TimeUnits.SECOND);
```

This way the monitor gets an exception if the result is not ready by the allowed time.

As a final note, consider that the wrapped task will still be running and eating resources, so you may want to set a `shouldStop` flag to `true` from the main thread to stop the computation as early as possible.