# Long Active Session in PL/SQL Procedures

Tags: java, oracle

We are calling PL/SQL Stored Procedures in Java code. Sometimes the package is taking a very long time to return the result. Is it possible to come out of the PL/SQL call and write an log in java?

Please see the below Java code:

```
long startTime = 0L;
long endTime = 0L;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info("Starting Time PKGSM2_TOOLS Alerts Package      ------->"+startTime);
CallableStatement statement= con.getConnection().prepareCall("{call  PKGSM2_CONTROL_CHART.PROC_INDICATORCHART_ECHARANGE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
statement.executeQuery();
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info("Ending Time PKGSM2_TOOLS Alerts Package ------->"+endTime);
logger.info("Total Package Execution Time Duration of Alerts Package ------->"+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
```

In the above code if the PL/SQL package takes more time and the request resides inside the package. Is it possible to exit from the call if the package call takes more than 2 minutes?

And also what will be reason for Long Active Session Inside the PL/SQL Stored procedure?

Comment: what is your end target , to prematurely close DB session / process or Java process or both processes?Cancelling stored procedure process via DB driver is DB dependent so do specify your DB software.Also its not easy to answer **Long Active Session** reason unless somebody knows your procedure details as well as your system details well.

Comment: If we do not get the result from PL/SQL Procedure, after certain time (Ex:2mins) I have to just write in logger that error has occured in Package call. i have to write an error log from java. How to calculate the timer here that is it took more than 2 mins?

Comment: Ok. Could you please suggest some solution for the first question.

Comment: If you just wish to move on and log a message , you will have to move DB calling code in another thread , see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252187/how-to-stop-execution-after-a-certain-time-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Utl File

[Use UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/System-Packages/UseUTLFILEPUTLINEtowritealineoftexttoafile.htm),
[how to do file append in pl/sql](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2109364300346886722)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHAREFLE IS
  v_MyFileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  BEGIN
       v_MyFileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\','HELLO.TXT','a');
       UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_MyFileHandle, 'Hello Again for the Second Time! ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YY HH:MI:SS AM'));
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_MyFileHandle);
 EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
                ('ERROR ' || TO_CHAR(SQLCODE) || SQLERRM);
           NULL; 
 END;
```