# Set a time limit / timeout for a method

Tags: java, methods, timeout

I have a simple method like this:

```
public void foo(int runForHowLong) {
    Motor.A.forward();
}
```

Now a want to be able to pass an argument to foo(), which sets a time limit for how long foo() will run. Like if I send foo(2), it runs for 2 seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: run code for x seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029118/java-run-code-for-x-seconds)

Answer (score 6):

You can use AOP and a [`@Timeable`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.7.16/com/jcabi/aspects/Timeable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-timeable.html) (I'm a developer):

```
class Motor {
  @Timeable(limit = 1, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  void forward() {
    // execution as usual
  }
}
```

When time limit is reached your thread will get `interrupted()` flag set to `true` and it's your job to handle this situation correctly and to stop execution.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question on Stackoverflow: [Run code for x seconds in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029118/java-run-code-for-x-seconds)

It is exactly the same related to the requirements.

As I interprete from your question you'd like to have the method running for 2 minutes. To achieve that you need to start a Thread which you control for 2 minutes and then stop the thread.

Answer (score -1):

The `TimeUnit` class provides method required for this.
Check it out here: [TimeUnit in JDK 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

Comment: That doesn't solve the part of actually stopping the operation after x seconds.

Answer (score -3):

- If you want for it to run for two seconds, you can use
  `Thread.sleep(2000)`.  Note that `Thread.sleep(2000)` is more of a
  "suggestion" than a "command"; it will not run for *exactly* 2000
  milliseconds, due to scheduling in the JVM.  It can pretty much be
  simplified to be *roughly* 2000 milliseconds.
- If you want it to continue calling `forward` for 2 seconds (which would result in quite a few invocations of the function), you will 
  need to use a timer of some sort.