# Continuously pass in data to AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my Android app, I have a snippet of code, similar to [Run code for x seconds in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029118/run-code-for-x-seconds-in-java)

```
long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = t+15000;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
//useful calculation
}
```

And this code will freeze the UI thread, so I'm wondering if there's a way to continuously pass in data to my AsyncTask that will do the calculation in the background thread to avoid freezing?  Or is there a better way, or to keep calling AsyncTask from within my while loop?

Comment: Sounds like you want a Thread rather than an AsyncTask.  If something should continually process in the background, a Thread is a better fit.  AsyncTasks by default operate all on a single thread, so you shouldn't use one to do more than a few seconds worth of processing.  Beyond that-  what kind of data do you want to pass it, with what frequency?  A normal way of doing this would be via a synchronized messaging queue.  Passing data to a thread or task is possible, but easy to do wrong.

Comment: Look into the Handler or Service classes in Android.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm reading data (double) from a sensor, not a sensor on the phone, at very high frequency (at least to the eye), I'm not sure what, but it looks like 10Hz ish. Can you point me to a document or something?

Comment: A synchronized message queue with the sensor handler writing data to the queue and the thread reading (or waiting for data to be available) sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, use a Handler instead.

It goes like this :

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //READ HERE WHAT YOU NEED FROM THE SENSOR (useful calculation)

        //And then set the next execution of the sensor reading
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //runs 1000 milliseconds
    }
};

//Launch It for the first time
timerHandler.post(timerRunnable);

//Whenever you would like to stop it, use the following commented line
//timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
```